# PostgreSQL foreign key create error

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and trying to create table with foreign keys.But I got error below.

```
create table User_Role 
( 
    RoleId serial primary key not null, 
    RoleCode varchar(21), 
    Rolename varchar(30), 
    isActive bool 
) 

CREATE TABLE User_Account( 
    UserId  serial primary key not null,
    RoleId_ref int REFERENCES User_Role (RoleId) NULL, 
    Username text NULL, 
    Password text NULL,  
    IsActive bool NULL 
) 

CREATE TABLE User_Profile( 
    ProfileId  serial primary key not null, 
    UserId_ref int REFERENCES User_Account (UserId) NULL,
    RoleId_ref int REFERENCES User_Role (RoleId) NULL,
    FirstName Text NULL, 
    LastName  Text NULL, 
    Address   Text NULL,
    City  varchar(100) NULL   
)
```

first two table created successfully. But last table occur create error.

> ERROR:  column "roleid" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
>   SQL state: 42703

but I can't understand why.